# How to suppress BT logging in android logcat?

Tags: android, filter, logcat

I am trying to suppress logging output from BT since it spams my debug session.  The log looks like this:

```
07-14 11:27:46.800 I/dun_service( 1105): The value returned from dun_getusbmodemstate_fromsys is 2
07-14 11:27:48.775 D/BT HS/HF( 1284): cdmaDbm : -81, cdmaEcio : -70
07-14 11:27:54.090 D/BT HS/HF( 1284): cdmaDbm : -81, cdmaEcio : -70
07-14 11:27:58.460 D/BT HS/HF( 1284): cdmaDbm : -81, cdmaEcio : -70
07-14 11:28:03.060 D/BT HS/HF( 1284): cdmaDbm : -81, cdmaEcio : -70
07-14 11:28:09.420 D/BT HS/HF( 1284): cdmaDbm : -81, cdmaEcio : -70
07-14 11:28:13.770 D/BT HS/HF( 1284): cdmaDbm : -81, cdmaEcio : -70
```

and I am using this command line to watch logcat:

```
> logcat -v time BT:S
```

and yet it still persists to log.  I think the problem is that the component is actually `BT HS/HF` but I am not able to quote it appropriately.

I can use this command:

```
adb logcat -v time | findstr /v "BT HS/HF"
```

but that feels like a hack - besides, I might miss buffered output through the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a better answer than to post-filter the log with grep.

```
adb logcat -v time | findstr /v "BT HS/HF"
```